# This is a follow up to another post I had on splitting using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Before I was not able to get the split to work. Now it is working but only performing the calculation on the last list of the list of list.  I need it to calculate the efficiency on each of the players not just the last one in the file.

I am thinking a while loop before the calculation might solve my problem, but I am open to suggestions.

```
def get_data_list (file_name):
    data_file = open(file_name, "r")
    data_list = []
    for line_str in data_file:

        # strip end-of-line, split on commas, and append items to list
        data_list =line_str.strip().split(',')

        gp=int(data_list[6])
        mins=int(data_list[7])
        pts=int(data_list[8])
        oreb=int(data_list[9])
        dreb=int(data_list[10])
        reb=int(data_list[11])
        asts=int(data_list[12])
        stl=int(data_list[13])
        blk=int(data_list[14])
        to=int(data_list[15])
        pf=int(data_list[16])
        fga=int(data_list[17])
        fgm=int(data_list[18])
        fta=int(data_list[19])
        ftm=int(data_list[20])
        tpa=int(data_list[21])
        tpm=int(data_list[22])

        efficiency = ((pts+reb+asts+stl+blk)-((fga-fgm)+(fta-ftm)+to))/gp        

        data_list.append (efficiency)

    return data_list

    file_name1 = input("File name: ")
    result_list = get_data_list (file_name1)
    print(result_list)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're redefining `data_list` in each iteration:

```
data_list = []
for line_str in data_file:

    # strip end-of-line, split on commas, and append items to list
    data_list =line_str.strip().split(',')
```

Try changing the first `data_list` to something like `data = []`. Also, you can use `with` when opening your file so that things like closing are handled properly:

```
def get_data_list (file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as data_file:
        data = []
        for line_str in data_file:

            # strip end-of-line, split on commas, and append items to list
            data_list =line_str.strip().split(',')

            # Your definitions here...
            gp=int(data_list[6])
            # ...

            efficiency = ((pts+reb+asts+stl+blk)-((fga-fgm)+(fta-ftm)+to))/gp          
            data_list.append (efficiency)
            data.append(data_list)

    return data
```

However you could also look into the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module - it looks like you're dealing with comma-separated values, and that module provides a very nice interface for handling them.

Comment: I tried that and still got the same results. Only calculating on the last entry in the list of lists.

Comment: Unfortunately we have not gotten to the with statement yet, so it is not allowed.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon No problem - back to your original problem, when you rename `data_list = []` to `data = []`, are you changing your `data_list.append (efficiency)` to `data.append (efficiency)` and your `return data_list` to `return data`?

Comment: I guess I need to further explain what I am trying to get.  I want to get the efficiency of each player appended to the list in the list of lists that references that player.  Then I am going to create a tuple with the efficiency rating and the players name.  Then I will sort them based on the efficiency rating.  I have to create a list of the top 50 players of basketball history.  I have a problem with my calculation, because I am not getting the right answer, but right now I am just trying to get an answer. Then I will work on the calculation to see why I am getting the wrong answer.

Comment: In other words if the list for each player has 23 fields I want to append field 24 so I can call it out for sorting.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon What does the file that you are iterating through contain? Data for just one player or all players?

Comment: For all the players since they started keeping records.  I have made a file with only 200 players instead of almost 30,000.  Some players are listed more than once since they played on multiple teams.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon So each line contains data for a player, and you are trying to append the new `efficiency` metric to that line and then append that new list to the overall list, returning a list of lists that contains a list for each player that now has the `efficiency` metric as well?

Comment: That is correct. There are 23 fields for each player and I need to add the 24th so I can call it out using the data_list[23] call out.  I will then create a tuple with this value and the first and last name of the player so they can be sorted.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon Just made an update - it basically appends the `efficiency` calculation to your `data_list` and then appends that list to `data`, returning `data`. Does that work?

Comment: I got the calculation working but it is generating a list of the results, not appending the result to each players stats.

Comment: yeah now it is calculation and appending to the list for each player.  Now I just need to pull out the results, sort them and generate a print out.  Thanks.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon When your function returns the results, you can then pull out element 0 and element 24 of each list during iteration and create a tuple with that. Does that not work?

Comment: Yes I got the tuple created. Now I am working on the sorting.  As I understand it I need to use the "sorted" function, with the efficiency factor listed first in the tuple. Then I can take those results and reorganize them so that the results prints out in a first_name, last_name and finally the efficiency factor last.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon If you have a list of tuples, try `sorted(tuple_list, key=lambda x: x[1])` (if the second element of your tuple is the `efficiency`).

Comment: Unfortunately that is one of those neat tools that I cannot use yet.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Fall 2012\python\programing projects\final program\efficiency3.py", line 54, in <module>
    result_list = get_data_list (file_name1)
  File "I:\Fall 2012\python\programing projects\final program\efficiency3.py", line 45, in get_data_list
    sorted_player_tuple = sorted(player_tuple)
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()  This is the error message I am getting now.  My brain hurts from working on this.  Maybe the best solution is to go to bed and get a fresh start tomorrow.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon In that case, you can use the longer form - make a very simple function that takes one argument (`x`) and have the return statement say `return x[1]`. Then in your `sorted` function, say `key=MyFunc`, where `MyFunc` is the function you made. This will accomplish the same thing as the `lambda`

Comment: I could not get that to work either.  I am going to quit for the night and get some sleep.  Maybe fresh eyes will see the error of my ways.  I am probably not typing something correctly.  Everything is beginning to run together.  Thanks for all your help.  At least I am now getting my tuple,  I just need to sort it.  I thought I had the calculation working but it is not right either.  One of the rules of programming according to our textbook is that when you are stumped take a break. Time for a break. Again thanks.

Comment: @BoliverAllmon No problem, and that is good advice :) Also, take note of the error message you are getting - that is telling you that you are trying to compare a `string` with an `integer`, meaning that somewhere in your tuple a value you expect to be an integer is actually a string (or vice versa). I would suggest investigating that when you wake up :) Good luck with everything.